# Robot Framework how to get the values from list variable

Tags: robotframework

I'm using robotframewok 4.0

I have defined a simple list variable:

```
*** Variables ***
${BROWSERSIZE}   1400   900
```

Using this variable in a test case:

```
Log To Console    Size: ${BROWSERSIZE}, Width:${BROWSERSIZE}[0] Height:${BROWSERSIZE}[1]
```

the output is this:

```
Size: 1400 900, Width:1 Height:4
```

Shouldn't (according to the manual) the indexes [0] and [1] refer to the two values? Instead it seems they refer to the character...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your [variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-variables) as a scalar instead of as a list. When you indexing it, you are indexing a string,`[0]` is the first character `1`, `[1]` is the second character `4`.

Change `$` to `@` to declare the variable as list.

```
*** Variables ***
@{BROWSERSIZE}   1400   900
```